# how to properly make div tab in javascript to work with reactjs

Tags: reactjs

The code below hide and show `div` when various tab is clicked and it's working fine with javascript as per code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>

   </head>
   <body>

<style>
#t2, #t3 {
 display: none; 
}

#t1{
 display: block; 
}
</style>


<script>

function tablet(indices) {

  document.getElementById('t1').style.display="none";
  document.getElementById('t2').style.display="none";
   document.getElementById('t3').style.display="none";

  document.getElementById(indices).style.display="block";

}

</script>
<a onclick="tablet('t1')">Tab 1</a><br>
<a  onclick="tablet('t2')">Tab 2</a><br>
<a  onclick="tablet('t3')">Tab 3</a><br>

<div id="t1"><b>I am tab 1</b></div>

<div id="t2"><b>I am tab 2</b></div>

<div id="t3"><b>I am tab 3</b></div>
</body></html>
```

**Here is my Issue:**
Now I want to implement it in reactjs but `div` is not working as expected when any tab is clicked. it shows and hide all contents all together.

It is supposed to work like in javascript above. Eg. The content of `tab1` is automatically displayed. When I click on `tab2`, the content of `tab1` is supposed to hide so that content of `tab2` will display and so on.

Any solution or work around will be appreciated

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>

<script src="build/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/browser.min.js"></script>


  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


   </head>
   <body>




<div id="app"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {showing: true };
  }

  render() {

const { showing } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="container">
<b>Hello welcome</b><br />

 <button onClick={() => this.setState({ showing: !showing })}>Tab 1</button>
<button onClick={() => this.setState({ showing: !showing })}>Tab 2</button>
<button onClick={() => this.setState({ showing: !showing })}>Tab 3</button>

                <div style={{ display: (showing ? 'block' : 'none') }}>I am Tab 1</div>
                <div style={{ display: (showing ? 'block' : 'none') }}>I am Tab 2</div>
                 <div style={{ display: (showing ? 'block' : 'none') }}>I am Tab 3</div>


      </div>
    );
  }
}



ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));


</script>


   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look in here :)

```
    this.state = {activeTab: 'tab1' };

    <button onClick={() => this.setState({ activeTab: 'tab1' })}>Tab 1</button>
    <button onClick={() => this.setState({ activeTab: 'tab2' })}>Tab 2</button>
    <button onClick={() => this.setState({ activeTab: 'tab3' })}>Tab 3</button>

     <div style={{ display: (activeTab==="tab1" ? 'block' : 'none') }}>I am Tab 1</div>
     <div style={{ display: (activeTab==="tab2" ? 'block' : 'none') }}>I am Tab 2</div>
     <div style={{ display: (activeTab==="tab3" ? 'block' : 'none') }}>I am Tab 3</div>
```

For more questions comment in here

Comment: the accepted answer deserves an upvote too hehehehe

Answer (score 0):

If I was you I would use a map function that loops through the list of buttons:

```js
const buttons = [button1, button2, button3];

const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

const toggle = (index) => {
  console.log(index)
  setIsOpen(!isOpen);
}

buttons.map((btn, index)=> {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={toggle(index)}>Button</button>
        <div className={isOpen ? 'none' : 'block'}>Toggling</div>
      </div>
    )
})
```